ROS2 Bag Timestamps
The link attached states that the timestamp can be twofold.
https://github.com/ros2/design/blob/ros2bags/articles/rosbags.md#determinism
I could not find documentation for "rqt_bag" and "ros2 bag play" for handling the timestamps.
When viewing the bag in rqt_bag, are we seeing "received timestamp" or "published timestamp".
When we play the bag with "ros2 bag play", what is the mechanism of the publishing. Are we publishing at rate of "received timestamp"? Is the message header replaced with "received timestamp"?
